# Using today's date in a row of csv file

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to add the current date each time a new row is created in a csv file. This is my code:

```
today = date.today()
with open('data6.csv', 'a') as storage_file:
    writer = csv.writer(storage_file)
    writer.writerows(zip(username, password, ip_address, ticket, today))
    storage_file.close()
```

This is my error:
`TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable`

Comment: OK, what's your question? The error tells you exactly what the problem is. Maybe you need help switching the code to use `writerow` instead of `writerows`? Check out [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: BTW, `storage_file.close()` is unnecessary; `with` does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) (which takes a list of lists) and [`.zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (while generates lists) are used, each parameter must be an `iterable`.  `today` is not an iterable (presumably the others are).

You can use either [`itertools.repeat(today)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) which will return the same item over and over, or make a list of matching length such as `[today] * len(username)`.

Working example:

```py
import csv
from itertools import repeat
from datetime import date

username = ['Mark', 'John', 'Joe']
password = ['abcdef', 'password', '123456']
ip_address = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']
ticket = [123, 456, 789]

today = date.today()

# newline='' is a documented requirement for csv.writer.
with open('data6.csv', 'a', newline='') as storage_file:
    writer = csv.writer(storage_file)
    writer.writerows(zip(username, password, ip_address, ticket, repeat(today)))
    # close() not needed with a with statement
```

data6.csv:

```
Mark,abcdef,1.1.1.1,123,2023-04-07
John,password,2.2.2.2,456,2023-04-07
Joe,123456,3.3.3.3,789,2023-04-07
```

Comment: Will this work even if the dates are different?

Comment: @marina If the dates are different give a **list** of dates.  `repeat` was needed because your original problem was passing a *single* date (`today`).